# Cannot read Exif data from JPEG image converted from Base64

Tags: java, metadata-extractor

I am currently developing a small wrapper around the metadata-extractor library to be able to access a few metadata attributes on a JPEG from ColdFusion code. The JPEG data comes in to ColdFusion from a REST endpoint as a base64 string. I wanted to convert that string to a byte array and read the Exif metadata from the JPEG, returning the original creation date to ColdFusion as a string. I am unable, however, to read the Exif block from the converted byte array.

I tried using both java.utils.Base64 and javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter to do the base64 conversion, but in both cases metadata-extractor cannot find the Exif data. I opened the original source image in a hex editor and the Exif data is present. I also tried using metadata-extractor on the original image file and this worked fine, the Exif headers were present when I printed out the directories and tags.

This is the constructor for the class I am using to read the metadata:

```java
public ImageMetaDataReader(String base64ImageData) throws IOException, ImageProcessingException {
        // create the image object from the provided string data

        byte [] imageBytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64ImageData);
        javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(lexicalXSDBase64Binary)
        ByteArrayInputStream imageBytesReader = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
        fileMetaData = JpegMetadataReader.readMetadata(imageBytesReader);

        imageBytesReader.reset();

        // read the exif data as well
        exifMetaData = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes), imageBytes.length, FileType.Jpeg);
        return;
    }
```

I also tried, in a vain attempt, to use the ExifReader directly, but was getting the exception unclear distinction between intel and motorola byte ordering.

When I run the code against the original image, I get all the file headers, Exif data and all other tags that are actually present in the JPEG data. When I run it against the base64 string as shown in the constructor, I get a few JPEG directories, a few JFIF directories, and a Huffman table directory, nothing else.

I suspect that somewhere during conversion the byte ordering is being messed up given the exception I got above, but I'm not really sure what to do to solve it. The only solution I can come up with is to write the JPEG data out to a temporary file then read it back in, but I would rather not do that if there is a better workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer actually turned out to be in how I was initially creating the base64 string in my test code. At first I was grabbing the image as a BufferedImage then reading it into a byte array using the ImageIO methods. I simplified the test code to look like this:

```java
        byte [] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(new File("duck.jpeg").toPath());
        String base64Image = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);

        ImageMetaDataReader reader = new ImageMetaDataReader(base64Image);
        printResult(reader.getImageMetaData(), "imageMetaDataTest()");
```

And now I get all the metadata. The only thing I can figure is that the ImageIO functions somehow were wiping out / corrupting the Exif data when I would read the image data into the byte array.